# Trim space for a column In sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I possible trim a white space before my column. I have a column called Cost and I have given a white space before.

```
[ Cost] [int] NULL,
```

I am using these queries and doesn't work. Can anyone correct me.

```
SELECT REPLACE(Cost, ' ', '')

select REPLACE (' Cost', ' ', '' )
```

Comment: Use `ltrim()` and perhaps `rtrim()`.

Comment: Try googling the title of this question maybe?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you should change table definition so that column name does not have white space in it. You can do that with `sp_RENAME` procedure.

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.[ Cost]' , 'Cost', 'COLUMN'
```

If you can't do that, you can refer column using square braces:

```
SELECT [ Cost]
FROM TableName
```